# server capability, requirements

Tags: installation, users

Ok, I am new here. Sorry if Im posting in a wrong way.

I work in a school where most of the employee downloaded movies and stuff that used most of the bandwidth while we have **a dedicated internet of 10M**.

I am thinking of having a new PC with good hardware and install windows server 2012 OS.

The reason is that I need to control the users access to some website and block some apps. our network is peer to peer with 4 switches and 1 router.

I am surprised that there is no server at all.

My question is, will the server handle 100 users in our organisation? Please not we do not have any other applications, just normal users

In addition, i found out we have a UPS so I can use it for the server :)

Thank you all.

Comment: I think your question might not be a great fit here (but check the [guidelines on asking](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) to see if you can make it a better fit), and I think you may be suffering from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - it sounds like what you need is some combination of proxy and firewall, and/or possible some kind of packet inspection ability.

Comment: I literally have no idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: I *think* your goal is to restrict internet access, which is usually achieved bydisabling direct internet access for your users and mandating the use of a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Monitoring_and_filtering) where you implement bandwidth controls and content filtering. 10 Mbit is not a lot of bandwidth to filter, but hardware requirements depend on both the software you select to do the filtering and the policies you'll be implementing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that completely relies on what server you're going to get and what it's purpose will be. With the information given, it's impossible to give you an answer.